# strtok function in C

Tags: c, strtok

I have a string, and I have to extract dates out of it. Form of dates is mm/dd/yyyy. So, first I separate tokens by " ", and when I know that a single token is a date, I want to use strtok on that single token with " /" parameter. It works great for first date, but after that it's not able to go back to finding tokens that are separated by " " (I understand why it happens, but I don't know how to do it without creating array of strings of all dates first, and i want to avoid it)

Comment: Can you use `strtok_r()`?

Comment: @Dmitri: The question does not even state it is multithreaded. And `strtok_r` is not C standard, but POSIX.

Comment: @Olaf So? How's that relevant?

Comment: If you have strtok_r (like on Linux) you can call it on multiple strings at the same time so then you could strtok_r the string for " " and then strtok_r the result for "/" to get the pieces.  I haven't thought of anything clever for if you don't have strtok_r except compiling it yourself.

Comment: There is no actual question here. And source code is missing as well.

Comment: I think the question is, how do you avoid the array of strings that would be the niave way to strtok a string of dates into pieces?  strtok_r would work or you could use strpbrk to roll your own.

Comment: If `strtok_r()` isn't an option you could also restart the search for " " by passing a pointer to the position past the date token as the first argument to `strtok()`

Comment: For context, when I said "How's that relevant?", Olaf's comment only said "The question does not even state it is multithreaded."

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

You should declare a `char*` variable for each separate tokenization you want to do at once. So declare one for splitting by spaces, and one for splitting by slashes. This is for `strtok` to remember how far it got.

Change `strtok` to `strtok_r`, and pass the address of one of these variables as the new last parameter.

Something like this:

```
char *spaceSplitState;
char *spaceToken = strtok_r(myString, " ", &spaceSplitState);
while(spaceToken)
{
    char *slashSplitState;
    char *slashToken = strtok_r(spaceToken, "/", &slashSplitState);
    while(slashToken)
    {
        // do something
        slashToken = strtok_r(myString, "/", &slashSplitState);
    }
    spaceToken = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &spaceSplitState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to separating the full string with and date string with `strtok_r`, another method you can use to handle any re-entrant situation, is to simply walk a pointer down your string checking each character as you go. You can easily parse the date components from the date string once isolated with a simple pair of pointers. You can either use `strchr` to orient the pointer position within the date string, or simply walk a pointer down the date string using a loop and advancing the pointer as you go.

(you can also use *array index* notation to move down the length of the string if your prefer that, e.g. `string[i]`, with `i` from `0` to `< length`)

For example, after you confirm you have a date in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`, using a *pointer* `p` and *end-pointer* `ep`, you can make 2 calls to `strchr` to find each `'/'` and copy the date components to wherever you choose to store them. (separate `m`, `d`, and `y` arrays are used below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    const char *dtstr = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    char *p = (char *)dtstr, *ep;
    char m[3] = "", d[3] = "", y[5] = "";

    /* locate 1st '/', copy, validate, advance pointer */
    if (!(ep = strchr (p, '/'))) return 1; 
    if (ep - p < 3 && strncpy (m, p, ep - p)) p = ep + 1;
    else return 1;

    /* locate 2st '/', copy, validate, advance pointer */
    if (!(ep = strchr (p, '/'))) return 1;  /* locate 2nd */
    if (ep - p < 3 && strncpy (d, p, ep - p)) p = ep + 1;
    else return 1;

    /* copy final year component */
    if (!strncpy (y, p, 5)) return 1;

    m[2] = d[2] = y[4] = 0;  /* affirmatively nul-terminate */   

    printf ("\n %s/%s/%s\n\n", m, d, y);

    return 0;
}
```

In somewhat of a simplification, you can use a loop to step through each character in your date string and do the same thing `strchr` does manually. The only difference in pointer names is `p` is the pointer used to walk (check) each character in the date string and `wp` is used for the *write-pointer* (simply a "in name only" change to help make their use clear).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    const char *dtstr = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    char *p = (char *)dtstr, *wp;
    char m[3] = "", d[3] = "", y[5] = "";

    /* parse each date component with simple pointer and loop */
    for (wp = m; *p && *p != '/' && wp - m < 3; p++, wp++)      /* mm */
        *wp = *p;   /* copy to m */
    *wp = 0;        /* nul-terminate */
    for (++p, wp = d; *p && *p != '/' && wp - d < 3; p++, wp++) /* dd */
        *wp = *p;
    *wp = 0;
    for (++p, wp = y; *p && wp - y < 5; p++, wp++)  /* year */
        *wp = *p;
    *wp = 0;

    printf ("\n %s/%s/%s\n\n", m, d, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Again, there is nothing wrong with using `strtok/strtok_r` to handle parsing the full string and then the date string as well, but you may find a number of circumstances where simply walking a pointer down a string (either using pointers as shown above, or array index notation, e.g. `datestr[i]`) is just as easy, if not easier. Using this type method, it doesn't matter how contorted your string is, or how many different *separators* are used within it, you have complete control by simply writing your conditional checks and moving the pointer...

**Example Use/Output**

In each case the output of each method is identical.

```
$ ./bin/ptrdate

 mm/dd/yyyy
```

Look over both methods, pointers and `strtok`. Each will have their advantages/disadvantages in any given situation. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `strtok()` requires a sequence of calls to work. If only the first sequence of calls to `strtok()` works for you, the most plausible reason is that you miss the 'initialization call' to set a different separator string for the second sequence (you have to alternate between space separator and slash separator, don't you?).
Posting you code with the loop would help to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

```
The short and simple program according to me would be

        #include<string.h>
        #include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char date[15];
char *dd,*mm,*yy;
gets(date);
char *token=strtok(date,"\");
dd=token;  //you get the date
token=strtok(NULL,"\");
mm=token; //you get the month
token=strtok(NULL,"\");
yy=token; //you get the year
}
```